# How does the quantum mechanical model of atom explain the fine spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I learnt that one of the demerits of Bohr's atom model was that it couldn't explain fine spectrum because the atom would emit only certain values of energy when excited.I was wondering if the quantum mechanical model has resolved it..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine_structure

Comment: @G.Smith that links says, _"It is worth noting that_ [the fine structure] _expression was first obtained by Sommerfeld based on the old Bohr theory; i.e., before the modern quantum mechanics was formulated."_ which contradicts the premise of the question.